in postman cookies store but in browser not store
I've been using Postman to test my API endpoints, and I've noticed that the cookies returned by the API in Postman are stored within Postman’s cookie storage, but they don’t appear in my browser's cookie storage
Give me the solution to solve this problem.
enter image description here
This is the request code .
const { mutate, isError, isPending, error } = useMutation({
        mutationFn: async ({ email, username, fullName, password }) => {
            try {
                const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/signup", {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers : { 
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Accept': 'application/json'
                     },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ email, username, fullName, password }),
                });
                const data = await res.json();
                if (!res.ok) throw new Error(data.error || "Failed to create account");
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                throw error;
            }
        },

This is to set cookie code :
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

const generateTokenSetCookie = (userId ,res)=>{
    const token = jwt.sign({userId},process.env.JWT_SECRET ,
        {
            expiresIn : "15d"
        }
    );
    res.cookie("jwt",token, {
        maxAge : 15*24*60*60*1000,
        httpOnly :true,
    });
}

export default generateTokenSetCookie;

This is my servre js code :
import epxress from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import {v2 as cloudinary} from "cloudinary"
import cors from "cors"


import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.routes.js";
import usersRoutes from "./routes/user.routes.js";
import postRoutes from "./routes/post.routes.js"
import notificationRoutes from "./routes/notification.routes.js"

import connectMongoDb from "./db/connectMongoDB.js";

//last video time : 03:39:00

dotenv.config();
const app = epxress();

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name : process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key : process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY ,
    api_secret : process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.use(cors())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(epxress.urlencoded({extended : true}))
app.use(epxress.json()) // to parse req.body

app.use("/api/auth" , authRoutes)
app.use("/api/users" , usersRoutes)
app.use("/api/posts" , postRoutes)
app.use("/api/notifications" , notificationRoutes)

app.listen(PORT ,()=>{
    console.log(`Server is running on port number ${PORT} `)
    connectMongoDb()
})


Looks like you are making a cross-origin request, but have not told fetch to actually send/accept credentials? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RequestInit#credentials
